# jQuery change/toggle classes between buttons from inside PHP loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a set of 2 buttons inside a loop.

```
<button class="dislike-btn" data-id="dislikeBtn-1>">Dislike</button>
<button class="like-btn" data-id="likeBtn-1">Like</button>
<br />
<button class="dislike-btn" data-id="dislikeBtn-2">">Dislike</button>
<button class="like-btn" data-id="likeBtn-2">Like</button>
<br />
<button class="dislike-btn" data-id="dislikeBtn-3">">Dislike</button>
<button class="like-btn" data-id="likeBtn-3">Like</button>
```

The desired functionality is for only one button in each set/iteration to be selected, which is achieved by adding/removing a class (`.dislike-btn-solid for .dislike-btn and .like-btn-solid for .like-btn`) from the other button. In other words, if a user clicks "Like" `.like-btn-solid` is added to `.like-btn` and if `.like-btn-solid` was selected on `.dislike-btn` before remove it.

I'd need help with the jQuery especially in selected the button Id's. I've tried different functions i.e closest(), hasClass(), removeClass() but get stuck by selected the right Id's. Clearly jQuery is not my strength so would highly appreciate a working example or pointers in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: This is what radio buttons are for. See http://www.html5-tutorials.org/forms/radiobuttons/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radio buttons would probably be a better tool for that, but if it has to be normal buttons:
You could set any `data-*` attribute that is the same for both buttons and then use that, something like this (not 100% sure if I got you correctly about how the classes should be added/removed):

```js
$('.like-btn').click(function(){
  var $button = $(this);
  var buttonNumber = $button.data('button');

  $button.addClass('like-btn-solid');
  $('.dislike-btn[data-button="'+buttonNumber+'"]').removeClass('dislike-btn-solid');
});

$('.dislike-btn').click(function(){
  var $button = $(this);
  var buttonNumber = $button.data('button');

  $button.addClass('dislike-btn-solid');
  $('.like-btn[data-button="'+buttonNumber+'"]').removeClass('like-btn-solid');
});
```

```css
.dislike-btn-solid {
  color: red;
}

.like-btn-solid {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="dislike-btn" data-id="dislikeBtn-1" data-button="1">Dislike</button>
<button class="like-btn" data-id="likeBtn-1" data-button="1">Like</button>
<br />
<button class="dislike-btn" data-id="dislikeBtn-2" data-button="2">Dislike</button>
<button class="like-btn" data-id="likeBtn-2" data-button="2">Like</button>
<br />
<button class="dislike-btn" data-id="dislikeBtn-3" data-button="3">Dislike</button>
<button class="like-btn" data-id="likeBtn-3" data-button="3">Like</button>
```

I'm sure you could do it in a single click handler for both but it will probably be clearer for you to have it seperate like this.